# How to use JavaScript in a loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, foreach, summernote

I have this javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote1').summernote({
            placeholder: 'start typing',
            lang: 'en-GB',
            height: 300, // set editor height
            minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
            maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
            focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        send(files[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function send(file) {
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                const urls = response.url;
                urls.forEach(imgurls);
                function imgurls(item) {
                    $('.summernote1').summernote('insertImage', item);
                }
            }
        };
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('files[]', file);
        xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
        xhttp.send(data);
    }
```

//second one

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.summernote2').summernote({
                placeholder: 'start typing',
                lang: 'en-GB',
                height: 300, // set editor height
                minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
                maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
                focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                callbacks: {
                    onImageUpload: function(files) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            send(files[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    
        function send(file) {
            var xhttp;
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    const urls = response.url;
                    urls.forEach(imgurls);
                    function imgurls(item) {
                        $('.summernote2').summernote('insertImage', item);
                    }
                }
            };
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('files[]', file);
            xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
            xhttp.send(data);
        }
    </script>
```

Then I have this html code

```
  <textarea class="form-control summernote1" id="summernote1" name="af_options[]"></textarea>

  <textarea class="form-control summernote2" id="summernote2" name="af_options[]"></textarea>
```

Now if I want to upload image in the summernote1, the image will be inserted in the last textarea which is summernote2.

Please how can I resolve this issue and is there anyway I can use 1 javascript code in all the textarea instead of repeating the javascript code because I have a foreach that loops a multiple textarea.

please help

Thanks for the solution....

Now how can I append more field... I have the code below but it is not working with the image insert

```
function add_more_additional_field() {

        $('#additional_options').append(
            '<textarea class="summernote" id="summernote" name="af_options[]" placeholder="Start typing the answers here"></textarea>'
        );

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $([...document.querySelectorAll('#additional_options .summernote')].pop()).summernote();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Please do not add an extra question in to the already answered question. Please aska new question on the site.

Comment: @phuzi Done

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621777/how-to-append-in-javascript-with-all-the-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second definition of `function send(file)` is over-writing the first one.

You should only have one definition of `send` and add a second parameter to include the correct textarea.

```
function send(file, $el) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            const urls = response.url;
            urls.forEach(imgurls);
            function imgurls(item) {
                // Use the passed textarea instead of a hard-coded value
                $el.summernote('insertImage', item);
            }
        }
    };
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('files[]', file);
    xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

To take advantage of this you will also need to update your `document.ready` callbacks. You won't be able to change the parameters of the `onImageUpload` callback so you will need to "embed" the correct element. There are a couple of ways to do this but I prefer creating a closure around a variable referencing the correct element as it will make it easy to refactor later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote1').summernote({
        placeholder: 'start typing',
        lang: 'en-GB',
        height: 300, // set editor height
        minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: (() => {
                let $el = $('.summernote1');
                return function(files) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        send(files[i], $el);
                    }
                };
           })()
        }
    });
});
```

This creates an IIFE that forms a closure around `$el` and passes this to `send()` when the onImageUpload callback is triggered.

You could do the same for `.summernote2` in your other `document.ready` for `.summernote2`

There is probably more refactoring that could be done to reduce the duplication of code even further.

Comment: @UposTyni, you may check my answer, you don't even need to use `let $el = $('.summernote1');` for each element.

Comment: @ikhvjs

How can I import the features in new textarea.... I use the below code to append it

` function add_more_additional_field() {

        $('#additional_options').append(
            '<textarea class="summernote" id="summernote" name="af_options[]" placeholder="Start typing the answers here"></textarea>'
        );

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $([...document.querySelectorAll('#additional_options .summernote')].pop()).summernote();
        });

    }`

Answer (score 1):

You can change all the classname as `summernote` and use `$('.summernote')` to select them all and apply `summernote()`.

The tricky part is store `$(this)` and pass it to the `send` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".summernote").each(function () {
        const self = $(this); // store self as this and this is referenced to each .summernote element.

        self.summernote({
            placeholder: "start typing",
            lang: "en-GB",
            height: 300, // set editor height
            minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
            maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
            focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function (files) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        send(files[i], self); // pass selft to send function
                    }
                },
            },
        });
    });
});

function send(file, context) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            const urls = response.url;
            urls.forEach(item => {
                context.summernote("insertImage", item);
            });
        }
    };
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("files[]", file);
    xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control summernote" id="summernote1" name="af_options[]"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<textarea class="form-control summernote" id="summernote2" name="af_options[]"></textarea>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$(".summernote", context)` just be `context`?

Comment: @phuzi, good spot! you are right.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than extend the original question.

Comment: @ikhvjs Done

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621777/how-to-append-in-javascript-with-all-the-functions

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting `send()` function definitions. Add the class as a parameter.

```
function send(file, summerclass) {
    ...
    function imgurls(item) {
        $(summerclass).summernote('insertImage', item);
        }
```

and pass from `ready()`.

```
send(files[i],'.summernote1');
```