# How to append in JavaScript with all the functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, foreach, summernote

I have this JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".summernote").each(function() {
            const self = $(this); // store self as this and this is referenced to each .summernote element.
            self.summernote({
                placeholder: "start typing",
                lang: "en-GB",
                height: 300, // set editor height
                minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
                maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
                focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                callbacks: {

                    onImageUpload: function(files) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            send(files[i], self); // pass selft to send function
                        }
                    },

                },
            });
        });
    });

    function send(file, context) {
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                const urls = response.url;
                urls.forEach(item => {
                    context.summernote('insertImage', item, function($image) {
                        $image.attr('src', item).attr('width', '100%');
                    });

                });
            }
        };
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("files[]", file);
        xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
        xhttp.send(data);


    }
</script>
```

I have this html

```
<textarea class="form-control summernote" id="summernote" name="af_options[]"> </textarea>
```

This works well with the javascript.

Now I am trying to append more textarea

```
function add_more_additional_field() {

        $('#additional_options').append(
            '<textarea class="summernote" id="summernote" name="af_options[]" placeholder="Start typing the answers here"></textarea>'
        );

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $([...document.querySelectorAll('#additional_options .summernote')].pop()).summernote();
        });

    }
```

but not all the functions like

```
 context.summernote('insertImage', item, function($image) {
                            $image.attr('src', item).attr('width', '100%');
```

was appended.

Please I need help on how to append more textarea with the exact function in the javascript to work like the one at $(document).ready() ... That is the one that loaded when the site was actually loaded

Comment: Why `XMLHttpRequest` when you have jQuery?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Where do you invoke your `add_more_additional_field` function?  There is no `#additional_options` element in your markup, so what do you expect that function to do exactly?  What do you mean when you say "not all functions were appended"?

Comment: Everything done in the `$(document).ready(function() {` is executed once, when the page is done loading, so `$(".summernote").each(function() {` does not include the elements added after the fact.

Comment: @LucaKiebel how can I reformat the code to include the elements after the fact?

Comment: Run the function inside the `$(".summernote").each(function() {` again when you add the new element

Comment: @LucaKiebel sample please

Comment: I tired ```    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editor').summernote({``` but didn't still work

Comment: @LucaKiebel how can I run the function again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a different id for each new `textarea`.

Example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".summernote").each(initSummernote);
});

function send(file, context) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            const urls = response.url;
            urls.forEach(item => {
                context.summernote("insertImage", item, function ($image) {
                    $image.attr("src", item).attr("width", "100%");
                });
            });
        }
    };
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("files[]", file);
    xhttp.open("POST", "/admin/ans-img-upload", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}

function initSummernote() {
    const self = $(this); // store self as this and this is referenced to each .summernote element.
    self.summernote({
        placeholder: "start typing",
        lang: "en-GB",
        height: 300, // set editor height
        minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function (files) {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    send(files[i], self); // pass selft to send function
                }
            },
        },
    });
}

function add_more_additional_field() {
    const count = $(".summernote").length + 1;

    const id = `summernote${count}`;

    $("#additional_options").append(
        `<textarea class="form-control summernote" id="${id}" name="af_options[]"></textarea>`
    );

    $(`#${id}`).each(initSummernote);
}

$("#add").on("click", add_more_additional_field);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add more</button>
<div id="additional_options">
  <textarea class="form-control summernote" id="summernote1" name="af_options[]"></textarea>
  <textarea class="form-control summernote" id="summernote2" name="af_options[]"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but only on the first textarea... it didn't work on the others

Comment: is like  const count = $(".summernote").length + 1; is not incrementing

Comment: thank you  @ikhvs .... I applied some wisdom and it works

Comment: @UposTyni, Could you upload your working answer and accept this answer if this help?